# change VPN configuration permission modal alert iOS

Tags: ios, vpn, ios-permissions

I've created app that connects iPhone to VPN(IKEv2) server. When I'm trying to connect to VPN first time it requires user permission in modal alert. Is there any way to change text of this modal alert? Didn't find any code in swift doing so. Info.plist keys, also don't contain something to do it. Is it possible? Moreover, I'm getting my app rejected by Apple App Review, because I don't properly explain to user why my app asks permission (I have privacy policy and terms of use in app, also I explain data collection in my app's description.).

Apple Review team:

> We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access their
>   VPN but does not clarify the use of this feature in the permission
>   modal alert.
>
> Please see attached screenshot for details.￼

[image: Screenshot attached by Apple.]

UPD:

I've got answer for my appeal and now waiting for call.

Answer:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for your response. Your call with an Apple Representative is
>   confirmed.
>
> An Apple Representative will call you on the number provided within
>   the next 3 to 5 business days from today to discuss your app.
>
> Best regards,
>
> App Store Review

Comment: Hello. Have you found solution? I’ve faced the same problem.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich hi, I've send appeal and now waiting for answer, will update this post.

Comment: any updates? Review team won't talk with me.)

Comment: @TimurBernikowich  I've got answer from them, but they still didn't contact me.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich I've got call.

Comment: @えるまる how to change the modal presentation or text or button for VPN default alert?

Comment: @SrikanthAdavalli I don't think that it's possible, but you can create your own designed alert after which you will show a system one. This is how most apps do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I've got call from Apple and they said:

> It is new requirement for VPN apps to explain how does they collect
>   user data in permission modal alert, but Swift wasn't updated to do
>   so. That is why you have to show information about data collection in
>   view where you will show prompt or show your custom modal alert.

I've added my own alert that forces user to agree with privacy policy and get approved.

Comment: Have you tried it already? I show such screen just before alert and still get such reject.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich No I didn't, but it was what they said while call.

Comment: Hey @Erumaru, did manage your app to get it approved by apple?

Comment: @ParthBhuva only after registering Apple Developer account as company.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich, did you display any custom alerts or system generated alert worked?

Comment: @ParthBhuva I explain what alert is for just before asking for permission.

Answer (score 2):

I've added text like "By starting VPN you agree with Privacy policy(this is link)" and get approved.

Comment: I've also did so, waiting for review.